# Modifying DIV innerHTML strips table tags

Tags: javascript, html

On a click of a button I want to add additional table row and cells into a `<table>`

`<input type="button" value="Add More" onclick="add_cust_fields()" />`

```
table rows and cells here
<div id="extra_cust_field"></div>
rows and cells continue here
```

My JScode

```
function add_cust_fields() {
    document.getElementById("extra_cust_field").innerHTML += 
        "<tr><td>test</td><td>test2</td></tr>";
}
```

All I got was bare `testtest2` above the entire table.

Comment: You need to append that stuff to the table element and not the div: `document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML += "stuff";`

Comment: You cannot have a `div` inside a `table`. The browser will correct this and move the div to a valid position. It seems this was above the table in this case.

Comment: can you paste the exact html? on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Your question worth for a downvote. Don't do javascript with tables. It is really difficult. Use only tables. Never concatinate strings for html. Use better solutions, (templating, jquery api, etc);

Comment: Downvotes are for badly asked questions if that's the case go ahead, bad practices can be noted in comments like you did so cheers.

Comment: I'm with Oybek here (though I disagree that you deserve a downvote). Add table elements via `document.createElement()` and `document.appendChild()`.

Comment: I'll play around with those but I kinda need the rows in a specific place in the table and I have no time to fine tune the appropriate methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<div id="extra_cust_field"></div>
```

to

```
<tbody id="extra_cust_field"></tbody>
```

and it should work.